# How to avoid to have my carrier resend information to my G2X after losing sms over 4g after instaling a rom

Tags: sms, custom-roms, 4g, t-mobile-g2x

Ever since I got that great/not so great phone I have been attempting to get a good version of gingerbread running on it since the stock version of froyo LG has on it is too unstable for me.

Every time I install a rom I it 90% functional but there is always something missing such as 4g, gps or network problems.

I had finally found a rom I liked but I discovered I could not send sms/mms over 4g anymore. It would say cannot send message with a red exclamation mark in a triangle). It still worked over wifi. So I did like I always do and restored back to froyo.

But this time the problem stuck!! I tried everything and finally had to call customer support. They resent some data to my phone and that fixed my problem. The tech support guy hinted strongly that my problem was because I installed a rom and said they could resend the data but nor "too often hint hint".

I installed at least 10 different roms before I had this problem. It appeared on rom: Hybrid - P999 Gingerbread 2.3.4 colorized from LG P990 UI - LG CAMERA - Rooted.

In the XDA thread there are a couple of guys who had the same complaint as me. The rom creator was quite upset we where accusing his rom but I had never heard of this problem in any other custom rom thread on XDA.

My question is! Can any rom do this and if so how can I avoid that? I am now afraid of installing roms and I like to do it so much!

My phone is a LG P999 branded as a Optimus 2X here in Canada. Carrier is videotron.

Comment: Do you know what they sent? I wonder if it was just the APN settings, which you should be able to enter manually (or backup/restore with something like Titanium depending on how compatible the ROMs are).

Comment: @MatthewRead APNs where fine as far as I can tell. He sais only they could do it (whatever it was they where doing). I went back to my stock backup apns where fine there.

Comment: Have you tried CM7 on the P999? I have flashed many roms on my Galaxy S and never had to have them send anything to my device to fix anything. I flash a new ROM at least twice a week as I try to keep up with the CM7 nightlies.

Comment: Well I did flash CM7 before but this problem I have is present in every roms I try. I ll try the latest cm nighty why not.

Answer (score 0):

After installing new ROM did you setup the APN for your network? If the custom ROM doesn't have the settings for your network your MMS wont' work. For SMS it needs correct message center number which in most cases is automatically provided by network.

Comment: Yes I had to do that often when instaling roms since they almost never have the settings for my carrier (videotron). But in this here problem I am back to stock with perfect apn settings and it fails.